# Limit step-by-step explanation required

Tags: limits

I have a step by step solution of a limit, but I do not understand it. The part that I have problems with is the last line, the second term of the sum, the denominator of the fraction. How come n(n+1) can be approximated by n? 
By the way wolfram gave the same answer, but step by step solution was unavailable.

[image: limit step by step]

Comment: When $n$ is large,$n+1$ is not very different from $n$.

Comment: yeah, but it would then give n^2 which would not yield the same result

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Whatever the value of $n$, $n+1$ is always 100% different from $n$.

Comment: @Did. I made a typo which induced a MAJOR mistake and when I noticed it, it was to late to edit my comment. Please, all of you, receive my apologies.

Comment: You could also take log of the function to get an indeterminate form of the type 0/0 and use L'Hôpital's rule to get the same limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+1/n)^n = e$. More precisely:

$$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n} + \frac{2}{n(n+1)} \right)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{3-n}} 
= lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \underbrace{ \left( 1+\frac{3+n}{n(n+1)} \right)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{3+n}}}_{\rightarrow e} \right)^{ \overbrace{\frac{3+n}{3-n}}^{\rightarrow -1}} = e^{-1}$$

Note that we can "pull the limit inside the bracket" because the exponential is continuous.

Comment: it's all clear now! I've tried something along this line (after failing with D'Hospital),but I missed the most important part. Thank you all for answers!

Comment: @studen You can check out the table  at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form if you're having trouble converting it to 0/0.

Comment: @Rhaldryn the problem was with the differentiation - it took too much time for such a smiple problem, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is $\left(1+\frac{1+x_n}n\right)^{-(1+y_n)n}$ where $x_n=\frac2{n+1}\to0$ and $y_n=\frac{4}{n-3}\to0$, and no further detail of the setting matters. Actually, the book merely uses, without mentioning it, the result  that, for every sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ such that $x_n\to0$ and $y_n\to0$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1+x_n}n\right)^{(1+y_n)n}=\mathrm e$. This is a generalization of the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\mathrm e$, with basically the same proof.